# if statement only executing on index 2 of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, coffeescript

I've this for loop in my coffeescript:

```
compareVersions = (current, minimum) ->
    console.log('current ', current)
    console.log('minimum ', minimum)
    current_parts = current.split '.'
    minimum_parts = minimum.split '.'
    for partIndex in [0..Math.min(current_parts.length, minimum_parts.length)]
       console.log('partIndex ', partIndex)
       if (+current_parts[partIndex] || 0) < (+minimum_parts[partIndex] || 0)
         console.log('current_parts.length1 ', current_parts[partIndex])
         console.log('minimum_parts.length1 ', minimum_parts[partIndex])
         return false
    console.log('PC current_parts.length2 ', current_parts[partIndex])
    console.log('PC minimum_parts.length2 ', minimum_parts[partIndex])
    true
```

It's designed to compare software versions and return false if the current version is lower than the minimum version.

I added the `console.log`'s to show what's happening.

This is the output I get. In this case the current version is higner than the minimum but the if statement only executes on index 2 which in this case has a lower number for the current than for the minimum.

```
current  3.4.1.35
minimum  3.3.3
partIndex  0
partIndex  1
partIndex  2
current_parts.length1  1
minimum_parts.length1  3
```

The if statement should execute for each iteration of the for loop. What is wrong here that is preventing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement is executing in each iteration of the for loop, but the current_parts.length1 and minimum_parts.length1 are printed when the if statement is true.

The execution of your if statement would be:

```
3 < 3 false
4 < 3 false
1 < 3 true
    print current_parts.length1
    print minimum_parts.length1
```

If you want to show current_parts.length1 and minimum_parts.length1, put them outside of the if statement so you will see the values when the if statement is going to execute.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working the way I want by adding this after the if: `else if (+current_parts[partIndex] || 0) > (+minimum_parts[partIndex] || 0)
            return true`

Comment: I see that you are using else if. Consider to use just `else` so it will take the ">" and the "=" conditions.

Comment: I don't want it to include "=" though.